# Position of interrogative auxiliary verbs as replies to statements

Tags: word-order, questions, auxiliary-verbs, question-tags

Imagine someone states the following to you:

> I think you're mistaken. We've never traveled to Italy together.

What's the difference between the following two responses, if any?

> Haven't we?
>
> We haven't?

I feel like there's a certain nuance between the two, but in reality, I can also see myself interchanging the two without any confusion. The difference I imagine is that former phrase has an implication of *I feel we actually **have** traveled together*, whereas the latter suggests more of a willingness to cede to the first person's statement.

Does anyone feel similarly? Is there any literature to suggest that I've drawn a logical conclusion?

Comment: *Syntactically,* the inverted verb+subject word order invariably denotes a ***question***. But probably any ***statement*** (using standard subject+verb order) can be presented as a question simply by intonation. I think any difference in nuance (which I don't see at all in OP's context) is purely a matter of opinion, and would not be generally or consistently recognised.

Comment: Far more depends on the intonation than anything else. Writing can only award or deny the question mark, and order the words in one of two ways. That's not even close to the possible meanings that can be conveyed in a dialog like this. There's nothing semantic that distinguishes the two word orders, especially; both can be varied intonationally in far more than two ways.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt that an authoritative yes or no answer supported by evidence will appear.

The information that is placed at the end of a sentence often receives more empahsis and can thereby change meaning. It could, therefore, be suggested that "We haven't?" ends with "not" and for that reason is more *negative* (skeptical). But the idea of pushing back information to give it emphasis would be overridden here by the fact that there is a much stronger reason to invert the subject and verb: It's a major way we make questions.

I would guess that the most important determiners of communicating the degree of doubt would come from intonation and nonverbal language.

However, in repeating them aloud several times, in several ways, I do find in myself a sense that the first might more commonly be used to express a stronger doubt. It also seems easier for me to pronounce *haven't we?* over *we haven't* with an intonation that makes a direct semantic contradiction: *In fact, I'm sure that we have* or *You know very well that we have.* If my sense generalizes enough that it correlates with a signifucant distinction operating in English communication, then one possible explanation (thus is only a guess) might be that the structure of *haven't we?* is the most common question variant form, and so could conceivably be more likely to be emitted and interpreted as more strongly questioning.

Finally, it might or might not add evidence that *Haven't we, indeed?* can be intoned (at least in my mind) to very clearly signify doubt or contradiction, while adding *indeed* to *We haven't?* doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score -1):

The organization of sentence structure is often about emphasis.  We create passive constructions to emphasize the direct object of verbs.

> The house was built by Jack.

We organize the sentence this way because we are talking about the house and possibly only regard Jack as a mild fact related to the house.  In this regard, the construction of the responding questions is absolutely related to emphasis.  Because both are completely correct grammatically, the choice of one or the other depends on that emphasis, but also (as usual) colloquial and dialectical norms.

I mostly agree with your assessment of the emphasis as well.  Of course, tone will play heavily in the question in either situation.  The first "haven't we?" could be used with surprise (imagine a very high-pitched inflection).  Likewise, any dose of doubt in the response will play heavily on the intended emphasis (imagine a somewhat sarcastic "we haven't?").

Comment: How does the active or passive construction of a declarative sentence relate to the question at hand?

Comment: The question at hand from the OP relates directly to emphasis in a sentence.  Passive constructions are created for emphasis.  Inverted sentences in general are the results of seeking emphasis.  Are they not?  And separating declarative and interrogative sentences does not help when they can be the exact same sentence (We haven't/We haven't?) but for punctuation.  So I pose the question to you, Jim, how are they not related?

Comment: It looks like a (well-written) tangent to me (-1 for now), but maybe we'd enjoy discussing. I'm often in  http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22937/the-english-learning-cabin where you can tag a comment to me if I'm away. I didn't intend to come across as strident.